# Find my iPhone can "online, location services turned off" show if someone has not turned off location services manually?

Tags: iphone, ios, find-my-iphone

Can "online, location services turned off" show if someone has not turned off location services manually? Is there any time that the location is unidentifiable, such as in a downtown area where GPS signals are not reliable?

Answer (score 1):

If location services are enabled and the location can't be obtained by the device because there's no GPS, etc, it will say so: 'location unavailable'.

The fact that it says the location services are off means literally that: the location services have been switched off.